# How do I re-install Zeitgeist Datahub in the Startup Application Preferences

Tags: unity, startup, unity-dash, startup-applications, zeitgeist

I stupidly removed Zeitgeist Datahub from Startup Application Preferences. How do I re-install it back there precisely as it was originally??
To put the question in another way: I did try to re-install it using the Add button on Startup Application Preferences, but then I was asked for a Command! I have no idea what that is or where to find it! What is the command? Where do I find it?
More importantly, how do I find out if Zeitgeist is even still installed in my system???
The reason I un-installed Zeitgeist from my Startup Application Preferences was because someone said it slowed the system down;
only later did I discover that Unity Dash will not work without it!!
I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is still installed by:

```
dpkg -s zeitgeist-datahub
```

If it is not, you can reinstall it simply by:

```
sudo apt-get install zeitgeist-datahub
```